# Output prints a value less than the final int

Tags: java

How would I make this program output 'invalid data' instead of 'total people' when the total people was less than 0?

Also, why is that when I enter a format issue at 'number entering' it prints 'total people' then sends me back to enter 'number leaving' again. How can I make it so that it prompts me to enter 'number entering' until valid?

```
 final int MAX_PEOPLE = 65; 
  final int MIN_PEOPLE = 0;
  int totalPeople = 0;  

  while (totalPeople <= MAX_PEOPLE) {             
     try  {  
        int numLeaving = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number leaving:"));
        int numEntering = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number entering:"));      
        if (numLeaving < MIN_PEOPLE || numEntering < MIN_PEOPLE) { 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid data");                                                                    
        }          
        else {                         
           totalPeople = (totalPeople + numEntering) - numLeaving;
        }
     }
     catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter numbers only");
     }  
     if (totalPeople > MAX_PEOPLE) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Capacity exceeded");
     } 
     else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total people");              
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I find you have 2 issues with your program

1. If an invalid input is entered in either "number entering" or "number leaving" it should prompt back to "number entering" or "number leaving" respectively.
2. It should output "invalid data" is the variable `totalPeople` < 0.

You could solve the first problem by creating a `while` loop for both `numLeaving` and `numEntering` and checking for invalid inputs till a correct input is received as illustrated below:

For `numLeaving`:

```
    int numLeaving = -1;
    while(numLeaving < MIN_PEOPLE){
        try{
            numLeaving = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number leaving:"));
            if(numLeaving < MIN_PEOPLE){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid data"); 
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter numbers only");
        }
    }
```

For `numEntering`:

```
    int numEntering = -1;
    while(numEntering < MIN_PEOPLE){
        try{
            numEntering = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number entering:"));
            if(numEntering < MIN_PEOPLE){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid data"); 
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter numbers only");
        }
    }
```

Now the above code eliminates the requirement for checking of `(numLeaving < MIN_PEOPLE || numEntering < MIN_PEOPLE)` as it has been taken care of. So you could simply calculate `totalPeople` and check if it is less than 0 and do the appropriate as illustrated below:

```
    totalPeople = (totalPeople + numEntering) - numLeaving;
    if (totalPeople < MIN_PEOPLE) { 
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid data"); 
       totalPeople = 0;
       continue;                                                                   
    }
```

I feel that these suggestions would solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the total because after performing the catch block, you are still hitting the output part.

Rewrite your code to keep the entire loop body in the `try` block so an exception causes the entire iteration to be bypassed.

```
while (totalPeople <= MAX_PEOPLE) {             
     try  {  
        int numLeaving = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number leaving:"));
        int numEntering = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number entering:"));      
        if (numLeaving < MIN_PEOPLE || numEntering < MIN_PEOPLE) { 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid data");                                                                    
        }          
        else {                         
           totalPeople = (totalPeople + numEntering) - numLeaving;
        }
        if (totalPeople > MAX_PEOPLE) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Capacity exceeded");
        } 
        else {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total people");              
        }
     }
     catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter numbers only");
        continue peopleHandler;
     }  

  }
```

You can also do this with a labeled `continue` statement to start a new iteration:

```
 peopleHandler: while (totalPeople <= MAX_PEOPLE) {             
     try  {  
        int numLeaving = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number leaving:"));
        int numEntering = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number entering:"));      
        if (numLeaving < MIN_PEOPLE || numEntering < MIN_PEOPLE) { 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid data");                                                                    
        }          
        else {                         
           totalPeople = (totalPeople + numEntering) - numLeaving;
        }
     }
     catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter numbers only");
        continue peopleHandler;
     }  
     if (totalPeople > MAX_PEOPLE) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Capacity exceeded");
     } 
     else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total people");              
     }
  }
```

Comment: I moved everything into the try block, but if I enter a format issue at 'number entering' it still kicks me back to enter 'number leaving' again

Comment: @dan I misunderstood your original quesrtion. You'll need to make a second while loop with a catch block inside that loops until there is valid input. You can use a `boolean` variable for this purpose.